# Possible to write a longer than 2-line txt file using batch code?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

I am working on a batch project and at the moment I am having some difficulty with making a batch file put more-then-one/ two lines of data into the txt file, for example, I have tried:

```
         echo jack.hales>>>options.txt
```

To attempt to get the text file to have the "jack.hales" on the third line of the txt file.

I am new to batch+txt files so if I am a bit dull on this topic I apologise.

Comment: You seem to think that the number of `>` indicates which line to write. Totally wrong. `>` means overwrite any existing file. `>>` means to append to any existing file.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not very clear but the following will do what you seem to be asking:

```
echo "line1" > options.txt
echo "line2" >> options.txt
echo "jack.hales" >> options.txt
```

Comment: What I am trying to do is to be able to specify where I want the text to be inserted, for example I want something on the third line and put 3 ">" 's inbetween the text I want in the file and the filename itself, it will crash the bash, so I was wondering whats happening there, because I am trying to make a config file for a batch program I am making and I am trying to put on a "reset to default" setting, if you were wondering why I was needing this. :) Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Nevermind! Working now I understand what you mean, thanks a bunch! 10/10 @DavilPostill

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is easier:

```
>options.txt (
line1
line2
line-x blabla
)
```